# Fixed navigation menu content not scrolling with page horizontally, when zoomed in

Tags: html, css

Is that possible, to do with CSS alone to force the nav menu to scroll with page content? If not, what should I do? I want it to be fixed on the top!
When I add overflow:scroll to #menucontainer div, it places a scrollbar just under the div, not on the bottom of the page.

Thank you.

Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q4f8nzqj/)

Here is the code:

**HTML:**

Layout

```
<div id="menucontainer">

    <div id="wrapper">

        <ul>

            <li><a id="Logo" href="#"></a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">új kérdés</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">új értékelés</a></li>
            <li><a id="Message" href="#"></a> </li>
            <li><a id="Notification" href="#">!</a> </li>
            <li><a id="Settings" href="#"></a> </li>
            <li>
                <form method="get" action="/search" id="search">
                    <input name="q" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Keresés..." />
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="Bodywrapper">
    <div class="LeftMenu">
        <a class="texttype2" href="#"> Kovács József</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="texttype1"><a href="#" id="person"> </a></li>
            <li class="texttype1"><a href="#" class="texttype1"> Üzenetek </a></li>
            <li class="texttype1"><a href="#" class="texttype1"> Értékeléseim</a></li>
            <li class="texttype1"><a href="#" class="texttype1"> Kérdéseim</a></li>
            <li class="texttype1"><a href="#" class="texttype1"> Exklúzív értékelések</a></li>
            <li class="texttype1"><a href="#" class="texttype1"> Válaszok</a></li>
            <li class="texttype1"><a href="#" class="texttype1"> Értesítések</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="Trends">
        <ul>
            <li class="texttype1"><a href="#" class="texttype1"> #asdasdasdasds</a></li>
            <li class="texttype1"><a href="#" class="texttype1"> #adasfaf</a></li>
            <li class="texttype1"><a href="#" class="texttype1"> #Hahahahaha</a></li>
            <li class="texttype1"><a href="#" class="texttype1"> #asdasdasdasds</a></li>
            <li class="texttype1"><a href="#" class="texttype1"> #adasfaf</a></li>
            <li class="texttype1"><a href="#" class="texttype1"> #Hahahahaha</a></li>
            <li class="texttype1"><a href="#" class="texttype1"> #asdasdasdasds</a></li>
            <li class="texttype1"><a href="#" class="texttype1"> #adasfaf</a></li>
            <li class="texttype1"><a href="#" class="texttype1"> #Hahahahaha</a></li>
            <li class="texttype1"><a href="#" class="texttype1"> #asdasdasdasds</a></li>
            <li class="texttype1"><a href="#" class="texttype1"> #adasfaf</a></li>
            <li class="texttype1"><a href="#" class="texttype1"> #Hahahahaha</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="Contentblock"> </div>
    <div id="Contentblock"> </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
background-color:lightgrey;}


#menucontainer {
position:fixed;
width:100%;
min-width:1280px;
height:45px;
background: #3f3f3f; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3f3f3f 0%, #000000 91%, #3f3f3f 91%, #33eb31 93%, #33eb31 101%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#3f3f3f), color-stop(91%,#000000), color-stop(91%,#3f3f3f), color-stop(93%,#33eb31), color-stop(101%,#33eb31)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3f3f3f 0%,#000000 91%,#3f3f3f 91%,#33eb31 93%,#33eb31 101%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3f3f3f 0%,#000000 91%,#3f3f3f 91%,#33eb31 93%,#33eb31 101%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3f3f3f 0%,#000000 91%,#3f3f3f 91%,#33eb31 93%,#33eb31 101%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3f3f3f 0%,#000000 91%,#3f3f3f 91%,#33eb31 93%,#33eb31 101%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3f3f3f', endColorstr='#33eb31',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 12px 4px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.64);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 12px 4px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.64);
box-shadow: 0px 2px 12px 4px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.64);
z-index: 2;
margin: 0px auto;}

#wrapper {
font-family: Arial;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 1em;
max-width:1280px;
color:#FFF;
margin:0px auto;
white-space:nowrap;
top:-3px;
position: relative;
padding-left:40px;}

#wrapper ul {
padding:0px;
margin:0px; }

#wrapper ul li {
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
line-height:45px;
height:45px;
display:inline-block;
padding-right:20px;}

#wrapper ul li a {
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFF; }

#wrapper ul li a:hover {
color: #33eb31; }

#Logo {
background-image: url(/logo.png);
background-size: 30px 30px;
display: inline-block;
height: 30px;
width: 30px;
min-width: 30px;
max-width: 30px;
top: 8px;
position:relative; }

#Message {
position: relative;
background-image: url(/30x42_standard_mail.png);
display: inline-block;
height: 17.5px;
width: 25px;
top:2px;
left: 280px;
background-size: 25px 17.8px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;}

#Message:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url(/30x42_standard_mail.png);
}

#Message:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url(/30x42_standard_mail.png);
}

#Message:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url(/30x42_hover_mail.png);
}
#Message:active {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url(/30x42_hover_mail.png);
}

#Notification {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
/*height: 17.5px;
width: 5px;*/
top: 3px;
left: 270px;
/*background-image: url(/30x10not_normal.png);
background-size: 5px 17.5px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;*/
font-family: Arial;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 1.55em;
width: 20px;
text-align:center; }


#Notification a {
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFF; }

#Notification a:hover {
color: #33eb31; }

#Settings {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
height: 22px;
width: 22px;
left: 253px;
top: 5px;
background-image: url(/30x30_standard_Controlpanel.png);
background-size: 22px 22px;
background-repeat:no-repeat; }

#Settings:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#Settings:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#Settings:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url(/30x30_hover_Controlpanel.png);
}
#Settings:active {
    color: #33eb31;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url(/30x30_hover_Controlpanel.png);
}

#search { }

#search input[type="text"] {
background: url(/search-dark.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #444;
border: 0 none;
font: bold 12px Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
color: white;
width: 150px;
padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
-webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
-moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
        top: -3px;
        left: 280px;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    clear:both;  }

#Bodywrapper {
margin: 0px auto;
position: relative;
max-width: 1280px;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
min-width:inherit;
     padding-top:40px; }

.LeftMenu {
font-family:Arial;
position:relative;
margin: 0px auto;
display:inline-block;
max-width:1024px; }

.texttype1 {
font-family:Arial;
font-size:1em;
text-decoration:none;
color:black;
list-style-type:none;
line-height: 24px;
margin: 0px auto; }

.texttype1 ul li {
list-style-type:none;}

.texttype2 {
font-family:Arial;
font-size:1.1em;
text-decoration:none;
color:black;
list-style-type:none;
line-height: 24px;
left: 110px;
top: 40px;
position:relative;
font-weight:bold;
margin: 0px auto;}

#person {
background-image: url(/person.png);
background-size: 40px 40px;
display: inline-block;
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
min-width: 40px;
max-width: 40px;
position:relative; }

.Trends {
font-family:Arial;
position:relative;
margin: 0px auto;
display:block;
max-width:1280px; }

#Contentblock {
background-color:white;
border-radius:1px;
height:auto;
min-height: 300px;
width: 800px;
left: 290px;
position:relative;
display:block;
padding: 20px;
top: -200px; }
```

Comment: Try using `fixed` [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: I am using, it causes the problem that I cannot scroll horizontally the menu

Comment: Ah, ok. You'd need to avoid `fixed` then and use a different way to keep the element on top.

Comment: Could you please give me a hand finding another solution?

Comment: See my answer below, complete with a working codepen example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the header at the top of the page but let it scroll horizontally, you cannot use `position: fixed`. You need to use a [different way of keeping the header on the top of the page](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwwMNx).

Answer (score 0):

The navigation stays put because you have specified `position:fixed` on the `#menucontainer` rule.

If you remove this, the navigation with scroll light the rest of the content.

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/q4f8nzqj/1/

Comment: Exactly, but I want it to be fixed on the top, that is why i use fixed :)